# iText Unit Testing and Automated Testing Questions

Tags: itext

I have been searching for some unit tests for the program iText with no luck.  Is anyone aware of any such tests?  Also, does anyone know if the developers use any automatic testing tools on iText, such as Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in iText7 in .NET Core 6. I know this question is old, but hopefully this helps someone.

Here's how we can test paragraph text fields like we have in the example below.

```
public class PdfHelper
{
    internal static Table GetTableCustInfo(string fName, string lName)
    {
       // This method would probably take params and be called from a public "build" method in this class

       var custInfo = new Table(1);
       custInfo.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
       custInfo.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
       custInfo.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(fName)));
       custInfo.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(Lname)));

       return custInfo;
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTableCustInfo_lNameProvided_lNameMaps()
{
    Table actual = PdfHelper.GetTableCustInfo("Popeye", "TheSailor");
    
    var actualText = GetTextFromCell(actual, 1, 0);

    Assert.AreEqual("TheSailor", actualText);
}

private static string GetTextFromCell(Table table, int row, int column)
{
    Cell targetCell = table.GetCell(row, column);

    IElement cellChild = targetCell.GetChildren()?.FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.IsNotNull(cellChild, "Cell child should exist");

    Paragraph childParagraph = (Paragraph)cellChild;
    Assert.IsNotNull(childParagraph, "Child's paragraph should exist.");

    IElement childOfParagraph = childParagraph.GetChildren()?.FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.IsNotNull(childOfParagraph, "The paragraph has no children.");

    Text paragraphTextElement = (Text)childOfParagraph;
    Assert.IsNotNull(paragraphTextElement, "Child of paragraph is missing the text element.");

    var textValue = paragraphTextElement.GetText();

    // Finally tracked it down!
    return textValue;
}
```