# iTextSharp comparing 2 PDFs for equality

Tags: itext

I am generating and storing PDFs in a database.

The pdf data is stored in a text field using Convert.ToBase64String(pdf.ByteArray)

If I generate the same exact PDF that already exists in the database, and compare the 2 base64strings, they are not the same. A big portion is the same, but it appears about 5-10% of the text is different each time.

What would make 2 pdfs different if both were generated using the same method?

This is a problem because I can't tell if the PDF was modified since it was last saved to the db.

Edit: The 2 pdfs visually appear exactly the same when viewing the actual pdf, but the base64string of the bytes are different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two PDFs that ***look*** 100% the same visually can be completely different under the covers. PDF producing programs are free to write the word "hello" as a single word or as five individual letters written in any order. They are also free to draw the lines of a table first followed by the cell contents, or the cell contents first, or any combination of these such as one cell at a time.

If you are actually programmatically creating the PDFs and you create two PDFs using completely identical code you ***still*** won't get files that are 100% identical. There's a couple of reasons for this, the most obvious is that PDFs support creation and modification dates. These will obviously change depending on when they are created. You can override these (and confuse everyone else so I don't recommend this) using something like this:

```
var info = writer.Info;
info.Put(PdfName.CREATIONDATE, new PdfDate(new DateTime(2001,01,01)));
info.Put(PdfName.MODDATE, new PdfDate(new DateTime(2001,01,01)));
```

However, PDFs also support a unique identifier in the trailer's `/ID` entry. To the best of my knowledge iText has no support for overriding this parameter. You could duplicate your PDF, change this manually and then calculate your differences and you might get closer to a comparison.

Then there's fonts. When subsetting fonts, producers create a unique internal name based on the original name and an arbitrary selection of six uppercase ASCII letters. So for the font Calibri the font's name could be `JLXWHD+Calibri` one time and `SDGDJT+Calibri` another time. iText doesn't support overriding of this because you'd probably do more harm than good. These internal names are used to avoid font subset collisions.

So the short answer is that unless you are comparing two files that are physical duplicates of each other you can't perform a direct comparison on their binary contents. The long answer is that you can tweak some of the PDF entries to remove unique parts *for comparison only* but you'd probably be doing more work than it would take to just re-store the file in the database.

Comment: Good answer. It is inherent to the file format that each PDF is unique, even if it was created using the same source code. Read my answer to the following question about testing for more info about the way you should compare PDFs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944424/itext-unit-testing-and-automated-testing-questions

Comment: Excellent response. I figured some hidden information (timestamps) was the cause of the differences. Ultimately I've found a way to pull the text from the pdf, and perform my comparisons that way. Probably not the most efficient method, but it works.